# Using money and improper dependency of monks on householders?

Tags: reference-request, monk, monasticism, vinaya, community

If one reads [this quote by a monk](https://ninjastream.to/download/n9JZrxK8gAG72/atid-370-uncensored-mp4), who is referring to [donations to SuttaCentral](https://suttacentral.net/donations?lang=en):

> ...For the past week or so, we’ve been actually losing money on Stripe: paying more in settlement fees than we get in donations.

- What should one assume in regard of observing Vinaya while letting people believe to act in preserving a noble tradition?

  *This seems to be referring to asking people to donate money,  to preserve a noble tradition (i.e. the scriptures published by SuttaCentral) -- but can they be doing this and observing Vinaya?*
- Maybe some can quote some related texts to money and relation issues from open resources on the matter to try to catch bite the tail (don't forget to donate...). What faults can come into play? What's required to make with things attained wrongly?
  What can be assumed when Bhikkhus share food and success, trade together with lay people?

  *To answer this question, perhaps quote from available from resources, on issues such as money and relationships. Are these faults?  Is this an example of Bhikkhus sharing food, and success, and trading commercially with lay people?*

Comment: I would rather not have Buddhism Stack Exchange's Q&A be used to slander and attack public figures or other platforms, or be used for political agendas, but Q&A about the monastic rules, is ok.

Comment: A moderator suggested this question we closed as "unclear". But I think I understood what you were asking, so I added my rewording of the question *in italics* to try to clarify.

Comment: Close is fine, since it will nevertheless just be used to feed defilements and hardly any with possibility to escape curruption to be found here.

Comment: It's not only asking but taking on it, handle it, do even unskilful and harmfull with the money...

Comment: See... either users here or there, without any compassion, selfish, blind, even assist in wrong doing. Who could prevent them from hell and war... nobody. You would pay everything that it fits your defilements, even give last chances... Later you will claim that the stackholder misused you and start to fight them...

Comment: Sigh... This is not the first time you've made a strongly worded post about SuttaCentral, but I'm still not clear what your objection to them *is*.  Do you want them to close down and not present the dharma on the internet? that seems like a loss...

Answer (score 2):

According to the Theravada [Bhikkhu Patimokkha](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/sv/bhikkhu-pati.html) (quoted below), lay stewards of the monks or nuns should handle money, to my understanding.

If needed, exceptions or modifications to minor monastic rules can be made, based on [The Great Standards](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/ariyesako/layguide.html#modern). And not to forget "*If it is desired, Ananda, the Sangha may, when I am gone, abolish the lesser and minor rules*". ([DN 16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html))

> **Rule 10:** In case a king, a royal official, a brahman,
> or a householder sends a
> robe fund for the sake of a bhikkhu via a messenger, (saying,) "Having
> purchased a robe with this robe fund, clothe the bhikkhu named
> so-and-so with a robe": If the messenger, approaching the bhikkhu,
> should say, "This is a robe fund being delivered for the sake of the
> venerable one. May the venerable one accept this robe fund," then the
> bhikkhu is to tell the messenger: "We do not accept robe funds, my
> friend. We accept robes (robe-cloth) as are proper according to
> season."
>
> If the messenger should say to the bhikkhu, "Does the venerable one
> have a steward?" then, bhikkhus, if the bhikkhu desires a robe, he may
> indicate a steward — either a monastery attendant or a lay follower —
> (saying,) "That, my friend, is the bhikkhus' steward."
>
> If the messenger, having instructed the steward and going to the
> bhikkhu, should say, "I have instructed the steward the venerable one
> indicated. May the venerable one go (to him) and he will clothe you
> with a robe in season," then the bhikkhu, desiring a robe and
> approaching the steward, may prompt and remind him two or three times,
> "I have need of a robe." Should (the steward) produce the robe after
> being prompted and reminded two or three times, that is good. .....
>
> **Rule 18:** Should any bhikkhu accept gold and silver, or have it
> accepted, or consent to its being deposited (near him), it is to be
> forfeited and confessed.
>
> **Rule 19:** Should any bhikkhu engage in various types of monetary
> exchange, it (the income) is to be forfeited and confessed.
>
> **Rule 20:** Should any bhikkhu engage in various types of trade, it (the
> article obtained) is to be forfeited and confessed.
>
> ([Bhikkhu Pāṭimokkha](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/vin/sv/bhikkhu-pati.html), translated by Ven. Thanissaro)

Comment: "According to the Theravada Bhikkhu Patimokkha, lay stewards of the monks or nuns should handle money, to my understanding.", the Buddha never gave lay people duties, so the answer somehow has the idea as if money would be required. The Buddhas sons simple don't accept it, not order others to act on money, nor keep households... It's fundamental corrupt if learning rules to seek ways as usual on it.

Comment: What about starting with rules: 18. Should any bhikkhu accept gold and silver, or have it accepted, or consent to its being deposited (near him), it is to be forfeited and confessed.

19. Should any bhikkhu engage in various types of monetary exchange, it (the income) is to be forfeited and confessed.

20. Should any bhikkhu engage in various types of trade, it (the article obtained) is to be forfeited and confessed.

Comment: What's the mental handicape if starting with denying obligation at first place? Affliction with the evil within oneself?

Comment: Good to get known the outstand non-corrupt approach by a late Samana: [The Use of Money by Monks](https://pathpress.org/the-use-of-money-by-monks/).